# My Program continually loops and never meets requirements

Tags: java

Hello all I am working on this program that takes user input of 3 angles. The first method is inputAngles which tells user to enter values. I have to have it, if the user enters a value of more than 180 for angle1 or if they enter a value for angle2 such that the sum of angle1 and angle2 is more than 180 or if they enter a value for angle3 such that the sum of all the angles is not equal to 180 then they receive a prompt to enter that angle again.

I am having the program constantly loop and never move on to the next method. And the last angle just constantly loops and never ends up terminating.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    public int inputAngles() {
    
    int sumofAngOneTwo = angle1 + angle2;                                
      while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the first angle of the triangle :");
        angle1 = input.nextInt();
        while (angle1 > 180) {
            System.out.println("First angle must be less than 180");
            System.out.println("Enter the first angle of the triangle :");
            angle1 = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the second angle of the triangle :");
        angle2 = input.nextInt();
        while (angle2 < sumofAngOneTwo) {
            System.out.println("Sum of first two angles must be less than 180");
            System.out.println("Enter the second angle of the triangle :");
            angle2 = input.nextInt();
        }
         int sumOfAngles = angle1 + angle2 + angle3;
        System.out.println("Enter the third angle of the triangle :");
        angle3 = input.nextInt();
        while (sumOfAngles >= 180) {
            System.out.println("Try again");
            System.out.println("Enter the third angle of the triangle :");
            angle3 = input.nextInt();
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Well you never change the value of `sumOfAngles` so there's no way for the loop to exit.

Comment: In your sample, you don't define sumOfAngOneTwo, nor sumOfAngles.

Comment: Updated @GuyIncognito

Comment: You're still not changing the variable. When you do `int sumOfAngles = angle1 + angle2 + angle3` at the start, that's the value it will have until you change it again – if any of the `angle1` to `angle3` variables change, it won't automatically re-calculate the value of the `sumOfAngles` variable.

Comment: @GuyIncognito So should I move the initialization down the method just under angle2.

Comment: You need to have the sum equations inside their loops, because otherwise the values won't update and the loops won't end.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that this is not a statement of mathematical equality:

```
int sumofAngOneTwo = angle1 + angle2;
```

That is, it does not say that whatever the future values of angle1 and angle2, that sumOfAngOneTWo will be equal to their sum.

Rather, it is the programming operation of assignment, which at the point that it is encountered in execution, takes the value of angle1 at that time, the value of angle2 at that time, computes their sum, and assigns the result to the variable sumOfAngOneTwo.

Thereafter, changes in angle1 and angle2 do not affect the value of sumOfAngOneTwo.  That will remain unchanged until the execution of another assignment statement in which sumOfAngOneTwo appears on the left-hand side.

tl;dr - it's an assignment, not an equation.